# Is there a fail-fast way of synchronization in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

Let's say I have a code snippet like this

```
synchronized(obj) {
    do something;
}
```

If `obj` was already locked by some other thread, this code will wait until `obj` released and after that it will try to get the lock.

But I want to know if there is any way to jump over the code block if the lock can not be gained immediately?

Or put it another way, is there a way to detect whether or not an object is already locked ?

UPDATE：

Thanks for mentioning the `Lock` interface, but that require programs to obey the same contract, i.e, they all refer to a `Lock` object instead of the `synchronized` keyword.

I wonder if there is a built-in way of checking the locking status ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to acquire a lock you have to follow the same contract as everything else working with that object anyway...

Comment: @trutheality  Good point, thanks.

Comment: If it's OK for you to be tied to the Sun JVM, there's also `sun.misc.Unsafe#tryMonitorEnter(Object)`, as described here: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue194.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there a fail-fast way of synchronization in Java?

I think it is a poor choice of terminology to use "fail-fast" to describe what you are trying to do here.  Fail-fast implies that not being to acquire a lock instantly is a failure or application error; c.f. fail-fast iterators which throw an unchecked CCME.  That's not the semantic model offered by locks in general, or here in particular.  A better term would be "non-blocking"

Also, it is not clear that *silently* skipping a block of code because you can't acquire a lock is *useful* behavior.  In most cases, the application needs to know that the "skip" path has been taken.

These points aside, you can't do it using primitive object locks.

<sup>(OK, on some JVMs you might be able to use `sun.misc.Unsafe` to do this, but that's a really bad idea.  You are likely to find that your compiler, class loader or security sandbox stops you from using the `Unsafe` API ... as it should.  Besides, this API is not called "unsafe" for nothing!)</sup>

The [`java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) API has a method that allows you to attempt to gain a lock without blocking.  Specifically, the `tryLock()` method attempts to acquire the lock and immediately returns `false` if the lock is in use.

There are other higher level concurrency classes that you could use as ersatz locks; e.g. `Semaphore`.

---

> Or put it another way, is there a way to detect whether or not an object is already locked ?

Actually, that is a bit different ... and not entirely useful either.  Sure, you could (hypothetically) test if a lock is being held.  (Indeed some `Lock` classes explicitly support this.)  But that doesn't mean that you'd be guaranteed to be able to acquire the lock without blocking.  If you make that (incorrect) assumption, you've introduced a Heisenbug into your code.

---

> I wonder if there is a built-in way of checking the locking status ?

[Assuming that you are referring to primitive locks ... ]

No there isn't.  At least, not within the running application itself.  (A debug agent can do this, but it is not practical for an application to talk to its JVM's debug agent.)

If you want / need to do this kind of thing, you've got *no real options* that don't involve changing your application's locking mechanism.  That's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using java.util.concurrent.Semaphore it will allow you more control